# How to add new column in pandas dataframe based on values in two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

Example dataframe:

```
Item_Name  Order_Number
    Apple          1234
  Avocado          1909
    Mango          1234
   Banana          1909
   Lychee          2605
```

Lets assume that my favorite item is anything that starts with an 'A'. I want to have a new column called my_favorites. It should say "Favorite" for all the rows where Item_Name starts with an A. Moreover, for all the other rows if the order number is same any item that starts with an A, it should also have "Favorite" as the value for my_favorites column. So ideally, everything except lychee should say "Favorite" in the new column.

This was my approach but it doesn't work:
I first created a list of order_numbers for any item_name that starts with an 'A'. Then I tried to  loop over the dataframe to see for each row if the order number matches any item on the list. If it does, add favorite to the new column else not favorite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fill `Favorite` column in one step. Select all `Order_Number` in the dataframe which the `Item_Name` starts by 'A':

```
df['Favorite'] = df['Order_Number'].isin(
        df.loc[df['Item_Name'].str.startswith('A'), 'Order_Number']) \
    .replace({True: 'favorite', False: 'not favorite'})
```

```
>>> df
  Item_Name  Order_Number      Favorite
0     Apple          1234      favorite
1   Avocado          1909      favorite
2     Mango          1234      favorite
3    Banana          1909      favorite
4    Lychee          2605  not favorite
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I dont want true/false in the favorite column. I want it to say either 'favorite' or 'not favorite'. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different answer to Corralien, but achieves the same result:

```py
df['my_favorites'] = df['Item_Name'].apply(lambda x: 'Favorite' if x.startswith('A')==True else 'Not Fav')
o = df[df['my_favorites']=='Favorite']['Order_Number'].values
df['my_favorites'] = df['Order_Number'].apply(lambda x: 'Favorite' if x in o else 'Not Fav')
```

In first line gets the Favorite item.
Second line, we get the list of all the orders with favorite items.
Third line we update the column with the same order as favorite items starting with 'A'.

Now when using ".startswith()" method remember that its case sensitive.